# Loading image from storage

Tags: codenameone

I have an image that I loaded by using URLImage class. Here is the code:

```
EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(getWidth()/2, getWidth()/2 , 0xF92D2D), true);
Image originImg = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, imgFileName, photo_url);
```

To my understanding, this image is being saved into Storage with `createToStorage()` method. However, next time when I am loading this form, I don't want to download the image again, I want to take it from the Storage, because its faster.
So what I did, I added check :

```
if (Storage.getInstance().exists(imgFileName)) {
        // Take the image from the Storage
    originImg = Image.createImage(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(imgFileName));
} else {
        // Load the image with URLImage class.
}
```

However, it seems like my file is never saved into the Storage. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. `URLImage` seamlessly loads the file from storage if the file is already there. You can open the network monitor and see if a request is made to the URL for this specific image.

I'm not sure why the `Storage.getInstance().exists(imgFileName)` method would fail. I assume the image name is different in the different execution or something of that sort. You can see that images are created in your `.cn1` directory.

Comment: I believe it was failing because I was calling connection request again, and even though it returned the same values, the Storage for some reasons didn't recognize the file anymore. (for example, the Storage recognized file before I called request, but after request it didn't recognize - even though the name of the file was the same).